# <td style="width"> attribute works inline but not in external stylesheet

Tags: css, html, html-table, css-tables, column-width

I'm trying to use external css to format a 3-column table with 100% width and column widths of 10%, 80%, and 10% respectively. All my td attributes work from the external stylesheet except width.

```
<td style="width:10%">
```

works in inline css, but not as an internal style or from the external stylesheet.
It will read td widths from the external css if I remove the 100% width attribute from the table, but then the width of my table changes depending on the amount of text in it.
I have tried using

```
table-layout: fixed;
```

with no success. I've also tried removing width from one column at a time with no effect. All the examples I can find use pixels instead of % widths.

Have I missed something simple about table design?

Here's the relevant part of my external css:

```
table.border td {
    border-width: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-style: ridge;
    border-color: white;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
}

 td.edge {
    background-color: green;
    width: 10%;
}
  td.center{
    width: 80%;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

and here's the table's html:

```
<table class="border" >
<tr>
<td class="edge"> hi there</td>
<td class="center">it's me</td>
<td class="edge"> bye there</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The table it gives me has a wide first column and narrow second and third columns.

Comment: Have you tried adding !important to the width?

Comment: Is it correct - table.border td, or it should be just table.border, or simply table? Also, it's better to use another class name, because "border" is a key word in CSS. Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct the CSS as follows (just removing "td" from this line: "table.border td") and it will work as expected:

```
table.border{
    border-width: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-style: ridge;
    border-color: white;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
}

 td.edge {
    background-color: green;
    width: 10%;
}
  td.center{
    width: 80%;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

This is jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/r281bv1z/

Hope this may help.

Comment: That did it! I had just figured it out and come to remove my question, and you had already answered me. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck with your project. Best regards,